# GCM and PhoneGap - register and unregister JS functions problems

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I have followed [this](http://devgirl.org/2012/10/25/tutorial-android-push-notifications-with-phonegap/) tutorial in order to test GCM with PhoneGap.

The app is launching, but I have 2 problems:

1. Function window.GCM.register("xxxxxxxxxx", "GCM_Event", GCM_Success,
   GCM_Fail ); doesn't triggeer the GCM_Event.
2. Function window.GCM.unregister( GCM_Success, GCM_Fail ); generates
       an error that sounds like this: ".. Activity
       com.cordova2.gmc.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver
       com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver .."

What is going wrong with this? Have I did something wrong?

I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/3B5lqCZVWjs) forum group where this 2 problems were mentioned, but no solution was given.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
windows.plugins.GCM.register("xxxxxxxxxx", "GCM_Event", GCM_Success, GCM_Fail);
```